# Initializing and accessing a pointer in a struct, that points to an array of pointers dynamically

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I had the task to implement a function that receives as params an int value of rows and columns.

I then have to generate a Matrix dynamically by using the received rows and columns.

Next I have to fill every coordinate of the matrix with 0.

Last but not least I have to return a pointer to the Matrix I just initialized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Matrix {
    int rows; // number of rows
    int cols; // number of columns
    double** data; // a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows; a row is an array of n_cols doubles
};
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

/*
* Creates a zero-initialized matrix of rows and columns matrix.
* n_rows = number of rows
* n_cols = number of columns
* return a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows; a row is an array of n_cols doubles
*/
Matrix* new_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols) {

    int i_rows;
    int i_cols;
    // Memory allocation of array of pointers -> array of n_row pointers
    double **positions = (double **)malloc(n_rows * sizeof(double *));
    // Row initialized as array of n_cols
    for(i_rows = 0; i_rows < n_rows; i_rows++){
      positions[i_rows] = (double *)malloc(n_cols * sizeof(double));
    }

    // elements of matrix are initialized as 0.0
    for(i_rows = 0; i_rows < n_rows; i_rows++){
      for(i_cols = 0; i_cols < n_cols; i_cols++){
        positions[i_rows][i_cols] = 0.0;
      }
    }

    Matrix *newM = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    newM->rows = n_rows;
    newM->cols = n_cols;
    newM->data = positions;


    return newM;
}

int main(void) {

    Matrix* test = new_matrix(2,2);
    printf("%.1f\n", test->data[1][5]); //Returns 0.0 allthough that should not happen


    return 0;
}
```

When I ran the program I didn't get any warnings or compiler errors, even though I tried accessing the index [1][5] in a matrix that should only have [0-1][0-1] elements I get 0.0 back, which should not happen. What went wrong?

Also when exactly should I free() the allocated memory in my program and how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I am now aware that my testing result is a consequence of undefined behavior and not due to errors on my part.

However I am still unsure how I can free up the memory of the dynamically allocated Matrix and at what point in my program do I have to do this?

Comment: Unrelated, `newM->data = positions;` - Why is `data` getting all the love? Shouldn't the `rows` and `cols` members get in on that action too ? That said, related to your "issues", your code invokes *undefined behavior* using `test->data[1][5]`. You commented "Returns 0.0 although that should not happen". I'm not sure what you were expecting, but it is on equal footing with what you actually got. Undefined behavior is just that; *undefined*. If you're *unlucky*, it may even appear to work correctly.

Comment: @WozCraig  Added the other struct components init in the function. I am not sure if this is undefined behavior or a mistake on my part. If  I printf in the main [2][0] I get a segmentation fault (core dumped), which was expected, however if I do the same for [1][100], it still gives me back 0.0

Comment: You may not be sure  if it is UB, but that's why you're here. I **am** sure, and so is any reasonably seasoned C engineer that reads that code. The compiler will generate exactly what you ask it, no less, and no *more* safe than said-same. Don't confuse *defined* behavior with *observed* behavior. The former predictably provides a path to the latter, the latter alone makes no guarantees on the former.

Answer (score 0):

Your Testing result is an undefined behaviour because you access an uninitlized space of memory.
The compiler can't give you a warning or an error because doesn't know the dimension of you array, because you declare it as a pointer.

To free the memory you can do this :

```
for(i_rows = 0; i_rows < n_rows; i_rows++){
      free(positions[i_rows]);
}
free(positions);
```

In this way you deallocate all the rows of the matrix and the the container of the rows. ( obviously "**position**" is the pointer to the matrix).

The free of the memory has to be placed after all the operation with the matrix.
In the example case you can put it in the main, after the printf.

I suggest you to create a new function to delete the matrix where you pass the pointer to the matrix and the number of rows.
For example:

```
void free_matrix(Matrix* matrix , int n_rows) {
    for(int i_rows = 0; i_rows < n_rows; i_rows++){
          free(matrix->data[i_rows]);
    }
    free(matrix->data);
}
```

And then call it when you need.